# Azure Stream Analytics Query with Machine Learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-stream-analytics

I have a stream analytics job running which gets data from event hub and save it to data lake store. The data inputted has a JSONArray of tags. If the array contains a tag that is equal to "weather", I save the data to the data lake. The current query is the following:

```
SELECT
    * 
INTO
    datalake
FROM
    eventhub AS event
CROSS APPLY 
    GetArrayElements(event.tags) AS arrayElement
WHERE
    arrayElement.ArrayValue = 'weather'
```

This query is working fine. My next step is to apply Machine Learning to the data. Specifically, the data has a field called "text" and I have added to the job a machine learning function called "sentiment". So I want to apply "sentiment" to "text" and output the result.

This [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-machine-learning-integration-tutorial) shows how to apply a sentiment function in the query. They show a simple example of having one input, apply sentiment, then output. I don't seem to be able to modify my current query to do the same thing.

Their query is:

```
WITH sentiment AS (  
SELECT text, sentiment(text) as result from datainput  
)  

Select text, result.[Score]  
Into datamloutput
From sentiment
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you defined a ML function named sentiment in your Azure Stream Analytics job?

Comment: Yes I have and I tested it and it works. I just want to integrate it into my query.

Comment: I assume you created and published the function with Azure Machine Learning Studio. Then, when you add the function in Azure Stream Analytics, did you define it as "Azure ML" (and not UDF or UDA)?